# convert polar stereographic projection into lat long grid in R

Tags: r, map-projections, rgdal

I have a polar stereographic grid (dimension are 6667 x 6667 cells, the exents are Top: 3333500,
Left: -3333500, Right: 3333500, Bottom: -3333500). The projection has a latitude of true scale -71 deg south, datum WGS84. The grid spacing is 1000 m

I would like to make a lat long grid from this but am having trouble. I may be going about this completely wrong but here's what I have thus far:

```
library(rgdal)
x<-seq(-3333500,3333500, length.out=6667)
y<-seq(3333500,-3333500,length.out=6667)
a<-data.frame(x,y)
coordinates(a)= ~x + y

stere <- "+proj=stere +lat_ts=-71 +datum=WGS84 +units=m"
#i have also tried:
#stere <- "+proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lat_ts=-71 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84  "
proj4string(a)<-CRS(stere) 
spTransform(a,CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
```

The output from spTransform is not correct. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't units be meters?

Comment: yes sorry typo @yosukesabai, still doesnt work

Comment: Did you find something close to your needs? Your grid is huge with millions of cells, which may be difficult to work with and even represent (map) it. It may be a better idea to work with rasterLayers instead.

Answer (score 5):

Would this be of any help?

```
#Load packages

kpacks <- c("rgdal", 'ggplot2', 'maptools', 'raster')
new.packs <- kpacks[!(kpacks %in% installed.packages()[ ,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packs)) install.packages(new.packs)
lapply(kpacks, require, character.only=T)
remove(kpacks, new.packs)

#Your GRID limits

x<-seq(-3333500,-3333000, length.out=10)
y<-seq(-3333000,-3333500,length.out=10)
xy <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(x,y))
coordinates(xy)= ~Var1 + Var2
plot(xy, axes = T)
```

[image: epsg 3031]

```
proj.pol <- CRS('+init=epsg:3031')
wgs <- CRS('+init=epsg:4326')
proj4string(xy) <- proj.pol
awgs <- spTransform(xy, wgs)
head(awgs)
SpatialPoints:
          Var1      Var2
[1,] -134.9957 -48.46152
[2,] -134.9962 -48.46184
[3,] -134.9967 -48.46216
[4,] -134.9971 -48.46248
[5,] -134.9976 -48.46280
[6,] -134.9981 -48.46311
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: +init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
+ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0

plot(awgs)
```

[image: wgs84]

And a more plausible example

```
data(wrld_simpl)
maps <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl$NAME %in% c("Argentina", "Chile",
                                          "Brazil",  "Antarctica"), ]
mapsdf <- fortify(maps)
x<-seq(-3433000,3433000, length.out=10)
y<-seq(3433000,-3433000,length.out=10)
xy <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(x,y))
coordinates(xy)= ~Var1 + Var2
proj4string(xy) <- proj.pol
awgs <- spTransform(xy, wgs)
#plot(awgs, axes = T)
awgsdf <- as.data.frame(awgs)

ggplot(maps) +
  geom_path(aes(x=long, y= lat, group = group)) +
  geom_point(data = awgsdf, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  #coord_polar()
  coord_map("ortho", orientation=c(-40, -20, 10))
```

[image: ggmap]

**EDIT**

Additional information on EPSG:3031 WGS 84 / Antarctic Polar Stereographic at [NCIDC site](https://nsidc.org/data/atlas/epsg_3031.html) or at [remotesensing.org](http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/proj_list/polar_stereographic.html)

**ADD Clip Grid to Extent**
You can define a region of interest to crop the Grid accordingly.

```
x<-seq(-12400000, 12400000, length.out=50)
y<-seq(-12400000, 12400000,length.out=50)
xy <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(x,y))
coordinates(xy)= ~Var1 + Var2
proj4string(xy) <- proj.pol
awgs <- spTransform(xy, wgs)
plot(awgs, axes = T)

# Create a extent object using raster::extent
ext1 <- extent(matrix(c(-60, 60, -86, -40), byrow = T, nrow=2))
awgs1 <- crop(awgs, ext1) # crop spdf to extent
# Plot it
ggplot(maps) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y= lat, group = group)) +
  geom_point(data = as.data.frame(coordinates(awgs)),
             aes(x=Var1, y=Var2), size = 1, colour = 'grey60') +
  geom_point(data = as.data.frame(coordinates(awgs1)),
             aes(x=Var1, y=Var2)) +
  #coord_polar()
  coord_map("ortho", orientation=c(-60, -20, 10)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Cool. Is there is list of all the "standard" EPSG projections.  I see I could change the URL on the NCIDC site but i didn't find a listing or index of them.

Comment: Thanks @PauloCardoso this was helpful. Is there an easy way to subset my larger grid by specific lat lon coordinates?

Comment: @Megan sure, by coordinates or bounding boxes for example. Your grid if too large for mapping and some manipulation. What exactly you need to do?

Comment: @PauloCardoso, I want to cut out a small box from the larger grid using 4 lat lon coordinates or whatever way is easiest. Im working on a super computer so manipulation/mapping isn't an issue.

Comment: @PauloCardoso, to be more specific, I want to plot a map of this small box and then, within the smaller box, I have a list of lat lons that I want to match to the grid and pull out the corresponding data.

Comment: @Megan How long you take to generate the expanded grid with the 6667x6667 coordinates and to render the ggplot? Did you try? The idea is to have a general rule to subset the area or do it to a specific box?

Comment: @PauloCardoso, it took about 10 minutes. I typically dont use ggplot so the coding is a bit foreign to me. I am wondering if it would be easier to switch the projection from polar stereographic into mercator and then the subsetting by lat lon could be more straightforward?

Comment: @Megan Everything is possible! It is justa matter of replacing EPSG codes, in this particular case change 3031 with the desired mercator (I'm not sure which is the appropriate here). I need to think about.

Answer (score 0):

From looking [at this documentation page](http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/proj_list/stereographic.html), It seems that `+proj=stere` requires both a `+lat_0` and `+lon_0` parameter. Using

```
stere <- "+proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lat_ts=-71 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m"
```

did seem to make a conversion (at least it had non-zero values).

```
proj4string(a)<-CRS(stere) 
z<-spTransform(a,CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")) 
summary(z)
# Object of class SpatialPointsDataFrame
# Coordinates:
#   min       max
# x -45 135.00000
# y -90 -48.45867
# Is projected: FALSE 
# proj4string :
# [+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0]
# Number of points: 6667
```